# Is model selection itself a model?

Tags: model-selection, ensemble-learning

Suppose that I wanted to choose from, for example, $Y = aX + \epsilon$ and $Y = aX^2 + \epsilon$. Is this meaningfully different from fitting $Y = a_1X + a_2X^2 + \epsilon$ and heavily penalizing $a_1a_2$? What about for model selection in general? Could we view it as a special case of an ensemble model, which must learn exactly one nonzero ensemble weight (edit: something like [bucket of models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Bucket_of_models))?